# overflow:hidden - element alignment issue

Tags: css, overflow

When I add `overflow:hidden` to `span`, it slightly moves up. What may be the reason ?

The span is dynamically in the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/beqrzypy/1/

I was trying to hide the dots with `text-indent` and add style to `span:before`.

```css
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 4px 7px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.holder{
  position: relative;
}
.moreitems{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 200px;
}
.moreitems li{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>sit amet, consectetur</li>
  <li>adipisicing elit</li>
  <li>Reiciendis</li>
  <li>ad minima om</li>
  <li>velit expedita</li>
  <li>impedit</li>
  <li class="holder"><span>...</span><ul class="moreitems" style="display: none;"><li class="">ad minima om</li><li class="">velit expedita</li><li class="">impedit</li><li class="">laborum earum</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to style the dots as in below design? I have trouble using large `font-size` with less `line-height`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `vertical-align: top;` in `li`, please check below code.

```
li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 4px 7px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "display:block" from the span.